# How to run a java dynamic web project from another machine using ip address

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have developed  a java dynamic web project and i am running it  now via **localhost:portnumber/project Name** using tomcat server 6.0. I want to make this project to be run from another machines also by hitting my machine ip address.

So how can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use your ipaddress of the tomcat server. Before that make sure that all the hosts are in same subnet or explicitly add the required configuration.

Comment: How to check whether all the hosts are in same subnet? I made some changes in server.xml file of tomcat server like added address="0.0.0.0". But it did not help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its very much doable. very easy if you are on same network. You can access it with below format

"YOUR_MACHINE_IP:PORT_NUMBER/project Name"

make sure the port is not blocked for outside requests. possible if firewall configured.

Comment: Yes, I already tried this thing "YOUR_MACHINE_IP:PORT_NUMBER/project Name" But it is throwing internal server error .How to check whether the firewall is blocking my machine ip address?

Comment: If its throwing "Internal server error" it means port is not blocked and request is reaching to server. please post your application & server configuration details